# Unable to escape pipe character (|) in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, escaping

I am trying to find number of pipe(|) characters in each line of a file. I am using following command to do so.

```
gc .\test.txt | % { ($_ | select-string "|" -all).matches | measure | select count }
```

Its not counting the pipe symbol.

I also tried

1. `|
2. '|'
3. |

Can anyone tell me how to escape pipe character in power shell?

If i am using strings or characters other than pipe the command is working properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A backslash `\` is the escape character for a regular expression.

```
gc .\test.txt | % { ($_ | select-string "\|" -all).matches | measure | select count }
```

If you're unsure, you can always use `[RegEx]::Escape()`:

```
$pattern = [RegEx]::Escape("|")
gc .\test.txt | % { ($_ | select-string $pattern -all).matches | measure | select count }
```

The pipe otherwise does not have to be escaped in PowerShell inside a string.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-SimpleMatch` parameter for `Select-String`, which turns off regular expression matching.

Comment: I think this is the right choice for this use, but I'll leave my answer for reference.

Comment: I tried with -SimpleMatch but its giving count as 0 although my file contains pipe characters i tried the command with |,'|',"|"

`gc  .\test.txt | % { ($_ | s
elect-string -SimpleMatch "|" -all).matches | measure | select count } `

Comment: When using `SimpleMatch` you don't get anything in the `Matches` property (because it's not a regex match). In that case use briantist's answer.