# Powershell Remove all lines except those containing certain strings

Tags: powershell, csv, search, edit

I can do this one-by-one with bookmarking and other Notepad++ features, but I will be doing this frequently to edit documents. I have used the below powershell for removing all lines except those containing a certain string, but how would I do it for, say 50 strings.

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\PATH\TO\FILE.csv'
$Pattern = 'word||'

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | % {if ($_ -match $Pattern){$_}} | Set-Content $SourceFile
```

Comment: If you have several strings the best way would be to place them into an array and loop through the array of strings while using the code above.

Comment: To clarify, each time I run this I have a set of strings defined after reviewing the csv. I was hoping I could just replicate `$Pattern1` through & `$Pattern50`, or have the strings listed in a txt file and use that.. is this possible?

Comment: @JasonSnell ok I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `$Match` should be `$Pattern` in your example.

You can specify multiple keywords in your pattern, like this:

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\PATH\TO\FILE.csv'
$Pattern = 'word|excel|powerpoint'

(Get-Content $SourceFile) | Where-Object { $_ -match $Pattern } | Set-Content $SourceFile
```

Comment: yeah sorry I was kind of in a rush.. i will give this a try

Comment: stupid question, what if my strings include the `|` symbol..? i.e. `word|`

Comment: @physlexic [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231674/unable-to-escape-pipe-character-in-powershell) (use a backslash to escape the pipe character)